# Converter um ficheiro EXCEL para PDF usando php

Tags: php, pdf, xls

Estou com bastantes pontas soltas, e preciso de uma ajuda para me por no caminho certo. Penso que não seja muito difícil, obrigado e resto de uma boa semana, Diogo Pereira.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está aqui o resultado mostrar no browser, que será para passar para PDF.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o ficheiro xls que está a ser "trabalhado"

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código em php para executar o ficheiro xls e mostrar no localhost.

Comment: existem varias formas, voce ja tentou alguma?

Comment: Boa tarde, eu já consegui passar o ficheiro xls (excel) para php e mostrar no browser, agora não sei como fazer para pegar nesse "display" do browser, ou página como lhe quiser chamar e passar para pdf.. usando php, obrigado

Comment: coloca na pergunta ai o que voce ja fez (codigos e tudo mais)